# PHP interface problem - class not found

Tags: php, interface

Hi I have a very simple class that implements an interface.  Both the class and the interface are in the same file.

When I implement the interface I get a fatal error "Class not found", but when I remove the implements and then try to use the class I can use it fine???

Can anyone offer any advice on this?

Sorry here is some code that I am using to test at the moment:

```
$tester = new TypeOneTester();
$tester->test("Hello");

interface iTestInterface
{
    public function test($data);
}

class TypeOneTester implements iTestInterface
{
    public function test($data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any code to reproduce an error?

Comment: Sorry, i have posted some now

Comment: Try to put class/interface definition at the begining of the file (before using it).

Answer (score 12):

Create an instance of your class **after the class and the interface are defined, not before.**

The order of definition in this case should be:

1. Interface
2. Class
3. Instance of Class (objects)

Comment: Why would that fail only when using interfaces though? i.e. when using normal classes and abstract classes then this issue is not present

Comment: While this is the solution (and fixed the same problem that I had), is this defined behavior or simply a bug in PHP?

Comment: This is a stupid php bug smh, but yes this is the solution

Answer (score 6):

This is a (very poorly) documented limitation:

http://php.net/manual/pl/migration5.incompatible.php

> In some cases classes must be declared before use. It only happens if some of the new features of PHP 5 (such as interfaces) are used. Otherwise the behaviour is the old.

I've filed a bug report nonetheless. IMO it should be fixed as it's inconsistent behaviour and the error message is not helpful for anyone who assumes as I did that PHP simply didn't care where you declare functions/classes. Come on, it's been there for over 10 years now...

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69665

Answer (score 3):

smells like a bug in php. Make sure it's reproducible with the latest version and post to bugs.php.net.

Reproduce code

```
interface I {}

$a = new A;
$b = new B;

class A {
    function __construct() { echo 'A'; }
}

class B implements I {
    function __construct() { echo 'B'; }
}
```

Expected

```
AB
```

Actual:

```
A
Fatal error: Class 'B' not found...
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because, php loading interface, and instantiate class class class object where there is a certain order and must be in a Php file, if the file is not in accordance with an order of 1. Require_one interface, 2. Require_one class